# Will a mediumblob cause any additional overhead compared to a normal column in terms of lookup performance?

Tags: mysql

Will a `mediumblob` cause any additional overhead compared to a normal column in terms of lookup performance?

I am well-aware that it will cause the standard disk overhead (the amount of bytes of the data + 3 bytes) per data inserted, but if I (for instance) perform a lookup that involves a `where` statement and a simple `join` on all other columns than the `mediumblob`, will the performance be different from if the `mediumblob` column wasn't there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: possibly not ;)

Long answer:

I recommend reading this interesting [blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/):

> With COMPACT and REDUNDANT row formats (used in before Innodb plugin
>   and named “Antelope” in Innodb Plugin and XtraDB) Innodb would try to
>   fit the whole row onto Innodb page. At least 2 rows have to fit to
>   each page plus some page data, which makes the limit about 8000 bytes.
>   If row fits completely Innodb will store it on the page and not use
>   external blob storage pages.

In this case, yes, you will most probably see decreased performances.

[Conversely](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html):

> When innodb_file_format is set to Barracuda and a table is created
>   with ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, long column values
>   are stored fully off-page, and the clustered index record contains
>   only a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page.

In this case, I expect the performance cost to be marginal, if noticeable at all. However, and as always, YMMV and you should test with your actual data set.

Comment: Barracuda was added in 5.5 (or 5.1 with the InnoDB plugin), so depending on your version of MySQL, it may not be available.